# What would the force arising from an $SU(4)$ gauge field operate like? (As in, how many charges, whether the boson would interact with the force, etc)

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, yang-mills

Heyo, i'm new to this all, and deadly curious what this would look like. If this isn't specific enough, lemme know.

Comment: It would be like QCD, but with one additional color and 15 bosons.

Comment: Neat! That was my guess- a fourth color, resulting in four colors and for anticolors - 4x4 SU(4) gluons, excluding the singlet, resulting in 15 SU(4) Gluons overall. Tinkering with the symmetry, I also noticed that there'd be eight corresponding fermions. Assuming electric charge in 1/3e, two would be negative, four would be neutral, and two would be positive. I bet this'd result in funny partial charges.

Comment: @QuinnJackson the number of fermions is not determined by the Gauge group.

Comment: Right, wording mistake. What I meant was, that I attached an SU(4) fermion group modelled off of the Eightfold Way just to further ape off of QCD for this toy model.